# Creating Enemy from List

Tags: c#, list, xna, copy

So I want to spawn in a random enemy from a List of enemies, but I can't find a clean way to create a new Enemy instance from the Enemy instance in the list. This is mainly because I have enemies of different object types (subclasses of type Enemy) entirely, so I can't simply copy all the attributes over. 
For example:

```
List<Enemy> EnemyDB = new List<Enemy>();
EnemyDB.Add(new Enemy(150,1.8f,"grunt"));
EnemyDB.Add(new EnemyOther(60, 5.8f, "bug"));
Enemy template = EnemyDB.[get random enemy];
Enemy toBeSpawned = ????;
```

How can I get a new instance of the list's enemy? Is there a better way entirely to do this?

Comment: All your enemies take the same constructor arguments? But I don't understand... Your list already contain instances, not template or definition. Why can't you just directly use them?

Comment: I can't have them all be the same instance because they all need independent positions, angles, etc.

Comment: So, why do you create instances in that list??

Comment: So I have a template to copy, they are specific enemy types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a "Clone" method on each Enemy subtype and call that method on the one you choose randomly from the List. You could also go "flyweight"; create a shallower copy that simply references the Enemy's more expensive members, like graphical elements (sprites, textures, skeleton), instead of making multiple in-memory copies.

Answer (score 1):

Change your definition of enemy to implement the [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) interface, or use the [Object.MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) method.

See also [Creating a copy of an object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569486) and [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389)

Comment: ICloneable is not a great interface conceptually (there's no information inherent in the interface to tell you how deep a copy the implementation makes), but functionally speaking it's pretty much what the OP wants. I didn't specifically recommend ICloneable in my answer, but the OP needs some sort of deep copy method, whether it's an ICloneable implementation or something hand-rolled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to, at least conceptually, make a distinction between *classes* of enemies (grunts, bugs, ...) and enemy *instances*. The class defines the *initial* health/hitpoints of an enemy, while an instance represents an actually spawned enemy with individual stats and a position.

There are two options to model this.

**Class/instance model**

You create two classes: one for the class of enemy, and one for an instance of enemy. The `EnemyClass` is a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28software_concept%29) for `Enemy` instances.

```
class EnemyClass
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int InitialHealth { get; }

    public Enemy Spawn();
}

class Enemy
{
    public EnemyClass Class { get; }
    public int CurrentHealth { get; }
    public Vector2D Position { get; }
}

// define enemy classes
EnemyClass gruntClass = new EnemyClass(...);
EnemyClass bugClass = new EnemyClass(...);

// spawn an enemy
Enemy enemy = gruntClass.Spawn();
```

**Prototype model**

There is only one class, `Enemy`. For each enemy class, there's a [prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) of an enemy instance of that class. This prototype does not exist in game. To spawn an enemy, you make a clone of the prototype.

```
class Enemy
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int InitialHealth { get; }
    public int CurrentHealth { get; }
    public Vector2D Position { get; }

    public Enemy Clone();
}

// define enemy prototypes
Enemy gruntPrototype = new Enemy(...);
Enemy bugPrototype = new Enemy(...);

// spawn an enemy
Enemy enemy = gruntPrototype.Clone();
```

Comment: The problem is, I need to use multiple classes in order to change things like AI and basic behavior. It's working fine right now with a multiple-class Prototype model (and overriding Clone methods for each class)