# Copy an object from a list into another object in the same list

Tags: c#, object

I have defined a list of objects as `List<NewLayerCounterMethod> NewLayer = new List<NewLayerCounterMethod>();` where each object within the class `NewLayerCounterMethod` has four properties such as: `VehicleType, VehicleCounter,Counter,Updating`.

The number of objects `NewLayer` is 10 and I want to copy `NewLayer[7]` into `NewLayer[5]` such that if `NewLayer[7]` is changed, `NewLayer[5]` will not be changed.

Please note that I do not want to make a new object while I want to replace the properties of one object with those of another object which makes it somehow different from other questions on Stackoverflow and I think it is not a duplication.

Comment: So you want to have a new variable which is _not_ a new object, but does not change the properties of the other object when one of its own properties is changed?

Comment: You can create event for NewLayerCounterMethod . When changed value you can access all data

Comment: @CompuChip Actually I do not want to create a new variable or object and I want to reassign one of the object. I have coded in MATLAB before and in MATLAB `=` do this while in C# `=` is reference type and any change in one of objects will affect the other. I

Comment: C# does a copy by default for value types. If you want value semantics, use a value type (change your `class` into a `struct`). Make sure you understand the implications, though.

Comment: @Luaan You mean if I change Class to Struct It works?

Comment: Yes, but note that this applies to all cases where you pass a value type (e.g. as an argument to a function) - so make sure to pass the values by reference where needed. And note that it *is* creating a new object, though the implications of that depend a lot on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you need to add a function to your `NewLayerCounterMethod` class, in which you copy all the properties of the other class to the new one. It would look somewhat like that then:

```
public void TakeProperties(NewLayerCounterMethod otherObject)
{
    propA = otherObject.propA;
    propB = otherObject.propB;
    //And so on for all properties left
}
```

You could add guards so that you only update the properties if the new value is different to the old one, but I suggest to add those guards directly to the properties.

The above method is than called like that:

```
NewLayer[5].TakeProperties(NewLayer[7]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the object, as otherwise you would just store the reference and in both fields and change them both. See this answers:

[Creating a copy of an object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569486/creating-a-copy-of-an-object-in-c-sharp)

[How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

Comment: Thanks but I think the recommended approaches make a new object. However, I want to re-assign `NewLayer[5]`