# Copy object data to heap location

Tags: c#, list, reference, heap-memory

I have the following code:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Number;
    public string Text;
}

System.Collections.Generic.List<Entity> list = new List<Entity>();
list.Add(new Entity() { Number = 100, Text = "hello1" });
list.Add(new Entity() { Number = 200, Text = "hello2" });

Entity sampleEntity = new Entity() { Number = 300, Text = "World" };

list[0] = sampleEntity // this does only replace the pointer in the list

list[0].Text = sampleEntity.Text; // this writes to the pointer in list
list[0].Number = sampleEntity.Number; // this writes to the pointer in list
```

What I would like to know if there is any possible way of performing a memcopy of the whole object data to the heap-location the `list[0]` entry points to? I mean in c++ it is a simple dereference `*list[0] = *entity;`

Comment: working at that level with .net is rarely needed. perhaps you might want to implement a clone method.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless `Entity` implements `ICloneable` (see [Creating a copy of an object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569486/creating-a-copy-of-an-object-in-c-sharp)).

I would personally just instantiate a new `Entity`.

`list[0] = new Entity { Number = sampleEntity.Number, Text = sampleEntity.Text };`