# Copy MVC model class object value to another object

Tags: c#

I have a class like

```
public class ControlViewModel 
{ 
  public string FieldType { get; set; } 
  public string FieldName { get; set; } 
}
```

and i create object ans set value for above class in controller side like,

```
ControlViewModel cvm = new ControlViewModel(); 
cvm.FieldType ="TEXT"; 
cvm.FieldName ="TEXT1";
```

Now want to copy `'cvm'` object to another object and change value 'FieldName' only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a copy of an object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569486/creating-a-copy-of-an-object-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using clonning of object

```
// Implement ICloneable to clone the object
public class ControlViewModel : ICloneable
{ 
  public string FieldType { get; set; } 
  public string FieldName { get; set; } 
  public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

ControlViewModel cvm = new ControlViewModel(); 
cvm.FieldType ="TEXT"; 
cvm.FieldName ="TEXT1";

// Copy object    
ControlViewModel cvm2 = (ControlViewModel)cvm.Clone() ;
cvm2.FieldName ="TEXT2";
```

MemberwiseClone() Creates a shallow copy of the current System.Object. ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx