# Modifying/filtering without mutating object

Tags: c#, functional-programming

Ok, let's say that I have some C# code that filters or restructures an incoming object (or list of objects), like so:

```
public Customer GetCustomer()
{
    var customer = _customerAdapter.GetCustomer();
    ModifyCustomer(customer);
    return customer;
}

private void ModifyCustomer(Customer c)
{
   //some changes to customer object
}
```

This works, but I'd prefer a more functional approach to this, i.e. keep incoming customer and return a new (modified one).

Is deep cloning the way to go? Is it recommended when coding in C#?

Comment: There's nothing built in to C#, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569486/creating-a-copy-of-an-object-in-c-sharp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net, and so on. Do note that this may be problematic if there's an ORM involved.

Comment: Isn't this a matter of changing `void ModifyCustomer(Customer c)` to `Customer ModifyCustomer(Customer c)` and trusting that the content of `ModifyCustomer` is doing the right thing?

Answer (score 1):

The closest built in feature is probably [records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types) and `with` expression:

```
public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName)
{
    public string[] PhoneNumbers { get; init; }
}

Person person1 = new("Nancy", "Davolio") { PhoneNumbers = new string[1] };
Person person2 = person1 with { FirstName = "John" };
```

Comment: Cool! Were not there yet (C# 9), but I will definately look into it, and use it in my own project until then!

Comment: @Cowborg records should not require any runtime change, so should be possible to use in .net framework by setting LangVersion in the .csproj, even if this is not officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use C# 9 then you can do something like this:

```
public class Consumer
{
   public readonly string FirstName;
   public readonly string LastName;

   public Consumer(string firstName, string lastName)
   {
       this.FirstName = firstName;
       this.LastName = lastName;
   }

   public Consumer WithFirstName(string firstName)
     => string.Equals(this.FirstName, firstName) 
              ? this 
              : new Consumer(firstName, this.LastName);

   public Consumer WithLastName(string lastName)
     => string.Equals(this.LastName, lastName)
              ? this
              : new Consumer(this.FirstName, lastName);
   }
}
```

[Related dotnet blogpost](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/immutable-collections-ready-for-prime-time/)